# Загрузка html страницы

Tags: javascript

Помогите хочу сделать на js загрузку html страницы, допустим я в свой сайт вставил код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.ru/vd.js"></script>
```

Я хочу сделать код в файле vs.js что бы он мне грузил html страницу я попробовал вот так:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "http://site.ru/test.html",
            data: "req=ok",
            success: function(html)
            {
                $("#messages").append(html);
            }
    });
```

Но он мне почему то не грузит содержимое сайта http://site.ru/test.html, подскажите в чём проблема

Comment: Оформите ваш пример тут http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @MNW, вам, очевидно, нужен не POST-запрос, а GET (хотя в случае с html это может и не иметь никакой разницы). Проще всего заглянуть в консоль (chrome - ctrl + shift + j) и посмотреть какие ошибки там выводятся, плюс посмотреть на вкладке network какие запросы уходят и какие ответы приходят (может понадобиться перезагрузка страницы). Возможно, у вас почему-то не выполняется кусок кода с запросом или элемента #messages в тот момент еще не существует.

Comment: `$('#object').load('/you_url.html');`

Comment: нужно также помнить, что если вы делаете запрос на другой сайт, то для эого нужно указывать параметр crossDomain